# Accidentally turned down SQL memory too low to log in, how do I fix?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I turned down the Maximum Memory of the my SQL Server instance to 15 MB... Now I can't log in to increase it. How can I increase the maximum memory without logging in?

Version is SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Connect using the [Dedicated Administrator Connection (DAC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189595%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), which is guaranteed a minimal amount of resources in order to solve issues exactly like this one. For example, if you are connecting via Management Studio, launch a New Query window and just type `ADMIN:servername` instead of `servername` when it prompts you to connect. Ignore any errors you get which are usually benign as they are associated with Object Explorer, the database dropdown list, IntelliSense, etc. also trying to connect on your behalf (only one DAC connection is allowed).

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178068%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), [here](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/08/dedicated-admin-connection-why-want-when-need-how-tell-whos-using/), and [some troubleshooting here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/sql-memory/test-your-dac-connection).

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively (since had it happen twice before and the DAC trick didn't work for me), shut the SQL Server service down, then bring it back in "minimal configuration" mode, which is a modified version of single-user mode.

Via the command line, go to the path for the sqlservr.exe executable, as listed in the service.  But instead of running `sqlservr.exe -m`, use `sqlservr.exe -f"sqlcmd"`.  This will ONLY allow connections from the named application, so everything else will fail, but you'll be able to connect, change the setting, issue the SHUTDOWN command from within SQLCMD, then bring it up normally.

Answer (score 7):

From the command prompt start sqlCmd using the Dedicated Administrator Connection (DAC). :

```
C:\>sqlcmd -S ServerName -U sa -P <password> –A
```

Once you are connected, execute the following to set the memory to 4 GB, it should be enough to allow you to reconnect using the Management Studio tool.

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
sp_configure 'max server memory', 4096;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

More on [Dedicated Administrator Connection (DAC)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189595(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem and didn't have luck with launching SSMS or the DAC, so hopefully this will help the next person who is in a panic.

I launched the SQL Server Configuration Manager (I'm running SQL 2017) on the server, selected "SQL Server Services" in the left-hand pane and then right-clicked on "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)" in the right-hand pane and choose "properties". In the Properties window, I went to the "Startup Parameters" tab and added the "-f" startup parameter. I restarted the SQL Service and it launched in "[minimal configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/database-engine-service-startup-options?view=sql-server-2017)" mode. I was then able to get into SSMS and correct the Max Memory setting. I then went back to the "Startup Parameters" tab and removed the "-f" parameter and restarted the service once again.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue, memory was set to too low by mistake. Couldn't connect using DAC, did the following:

1. `net start "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)" /f /m`
2. Connected using SSMS on the server directly and was able to reach properties and set the correct memory settings.
3. After correcting memory settings, run again:
   net start "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)"
   (without /f /m so SQL goes back to multi user)

Answer (score 1):

This is either done using the net start/stop command or by sqlserver.exe command. Let’s first check how it is done via net start/stop command
The syntax for a net start/stop command is
NET START  
The service name can be obtained as shown below.

1. Type services.msc in “RUN” window and click OK. This will open the service dialog box.
2. Navigate to the SQL Server instance you wish to get the service name for and double click it. This will open the properties dialog box for that instance. Copy the service name listed there.
3. **---enable service is a single-user mode**

   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn>net start "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)" /f /m
   The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service is starting.
   The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service was started successfully.
   Connected using SSMS on the server directly and was able to reach properties and set the correct memory settings.
   Or run below command:-
   sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
   GO
   RECONFIGURE;
   GO
   sp_configure 'max server memory', 4096;
   GO
   RECONFIGURE;
   GO

**--get out from single-user mode by stopping service**

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn>net stop "SQL Server (MSSQL
SERVER)"
```

To start the SQL Instance in multi-user mode, stop the service using net stop as shown above and then start it without specifying \m parameter as shown below.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn>net start "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)"
The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service is starting.
The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service was started successfully.
```

One thing to note here is that starting the SQL Server Instance doesn’t start the SQL Server Agent service.  In order to start the SQL Server Agent, get the service name using the method shared above and start it as shown in the above image.
Or
Go to services and enable it.